# VSIX project : Can't access to a custom command file template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, vsixmanifest

I'm trying to implement a first VS extension with this Microsoft tutorial :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138589.aspx

At the begining, they speak about creating a new custom command (with the "Add new item" menu of Visual studio). And I've got the same problem as mentionned in this thread : I don't find any item template named "Custom command".

I've created my VSIX project without problem before. And I've installed the SDK project.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem closing the solution and opening it again. 
After doing that the project node appeared and the add wizard contained the expected elements.